# iOS 8 setValuesForKeysWithDictionary fails on iPhone 5 / iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, serialization, ios8, 32bit-64bit

I have code that deserializes some json to an object. This code runs fine on iPhone 5s, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6+.

However, when running on an iPhone 5 or iPhone 4s, I get the error: `[__NSCFString longValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Here's the code:

```
public class Serializable : NSObject
{        
    func deserialize(dictionary: NSMutableDictionary)
    {
        /*  Remove entries from the dictionary that do not have a corresponding property on the target object.
        By default, setValuesForKeysWithDictionary() will cause the app to crash if it encounters the above. */
        removeInvalidProperties(self, dictionary: dictionary)

        self.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
    }        

    private func removeInvalidProperties(object: NSObject, dictionary: NSMutableDictionary)
    {
        for key in dictionary.allKeys {
            var exists: Bool = object.respondsToSelector(Selector(key as String))
            if !exists {
                dictionary.removeObjectForKey(key)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can't help but notice that the phones that run this code correctly are 64-bit architecture, and the ones that throw an error are 32-bit. I can only assume that this is a runtime compatibility issue.

Does anyone know what might be causing this, or how to get around it?

Comment: Great question. I'm getting the exact same issue. However on my server, I'm not sending the double quotes in codes. Same codebase, from one server, I receive the attribute value in double quotes and from another I don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One issue that could arise is if you had your properties mistyped when you were deserializing from JSON. I am fairly confident that the 64-bit runtime will automatically convert a string to an int but the 32-bit runtime will not.

Comment: That was it. I was getting `"id":"1234"` instead of `"id":1234`. I manually converted the offending occurrences, and now it works on all devices. Thanks!